# Getting Country Name from coordinates takes too Long

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data from  NASA websites which has bunch of coordinates and from these coordinates, I'm trying to find which country they belong via geopy in every 1 hour. But unfortunately it takes quite a lot to get the country names .

How can I reduce the process of time ?

Here's my code;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="geoapiExercises")

df=pd.read_csv("https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/active_fire/modis-c6.1/csv/MODIS_C6_1_Europe_24h.csv")
df.latitude=df.latitude.astype(str)
df.longitude=df.longitude.astype(str)


country_list=[]

for i in range(len(df)):
    try:
        location = geolocator.reverse(df.latitude[i]+","+df.latitude[i])
        country=location.raw["address"]["country"]
        country_list.append(country)
    except:
        country_list.append("None")
        print(i)
        continue

df_s=pd.Series(country_list)
df["Country"]=df_s
df.to_csv("map_data_R00.csv",index=False)
```

Comment: Define "too long". That CSV, at the time of commenting, has 846 entries. Geolocating 800 sets of coordinates is going to take *some* time.

Comment: The problem is that you can't pass a URL (str) as the first parameter to read_csv. See:- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Looks like geocoders is trying to resolve the exact address of the location you pass. That seems like a big overkill for what you're trying to accomplish. But this SO question seems to have what you need. I haven't tested it.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88011/from-coordinates-find-country-using-python

Comment: @DarkKnight actually it reads from path not url. I pasted url in order to show ppl how dataframe looks like

Comment: The delay comes from acquisition of the CSV. If you invoke that URL from Safari and do so repeatedly, you will notice that the content changes - i.e. it's being appended to on the server side. I have tried both requests and urllib modules and emulated precisely the headers transmitted in Safari and note that the response time is ~75 seconds. If I set a timeout of 5 seconds, then I get a response within that time (obviously). However, it's possible that the content will be incomplete. If you inspect the data in your browser, you will also note that the last line is usually truncated/incomplete

Comment: @DarkKnight From the docs you linked: `The string could be a URL.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is "slow" because, as it says in the [Nominatim Usage Policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/):

> No heavy uses (an absolute maximum of 1 request per second).

So at least it will take about `len(df)` seconds, as I think they apply throttling. Also, you might have been blocked:

> Clients sending repeatedly the same query may be classified as faulty and blocked.

If you want to speed it up, you can run your own instance of the service. The docs contain [instructions on how to install the software and import their data](https://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/admin/Installation/).

That said, your code contains a bug: you are using the latitude twice. Also, iterating over `range(len(...))` is a code smell in Python. I would go for something like

```py
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(
    user_agent="StackOverflow Question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68727013/383793)"
)

df = pd.read_csv("https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/active_fire/modis-c6.1/csv/MODIS_C6_1_Europe_24h.csv")

df = df.head()  # just to show an example

def to_country_code(lat: float, long: float) -> str:
    "Isn't this more generic than the country name as a string in the country's language?"
    return geolocator.reverse((lat, long)).raw['address']['country_code']
    
df['country_code'] = df[['latitude', 'longitude']].apply(
    lambda x: to_country_code(*x), axis=1
)
print(df)
```

```
   latitude  longitude  brightness  scan  track    acq_date  acq_time  \
0  44.48386   22.69465      310.45  2.20   1.44  2021-08-09       1.0   
1  42.92273   18.03089      306.02  3.97   1.85  2021-08-09       1.0   
2  42.91645   18.02446      307.58  3.97   1.85  2021-08-09       1.0   
3  41.26550   31.42957      302.74  1.01   1.01  2021-08-09       1.0   
4  42.02151   20.29289      300.76  2.87   1.62  2021-08-09       1.0   

  satellite  confidence version  bright_t31    frp daynight country_code  
0         A        80.0  6.1NRT      290.21  33.94        N           ro  
1         A        67.0  6.1NRT      293.46  42.59        N           ba  
2         A        72.0  6.1NRT      293.85  49.84        N           ba  
3         A        51.0  6.1NRT      292.64   5.38        N           tr  
4         A        33.0  6.1NRT      290.08  17.58        N           al
```

Before scaling up —since fire data shouldn't change too much— you could try caching the Nominatim responses.

This seems to work, after installing requests-cache:

```
requests_cache.install_cache('geopy_cache')
geolocator = Nominatim(
    user_agent="StackOverflow Question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68727013/383793)"
)
requests_cache.uninstall_cache()
```

If you —rightfully so— feel iffy about monkeypatching. The Right Thing™ to do would be to pick up [this issue](https://github.com/geopy/geopy/issues/375) in the geopy bugtracker.

Comment: Appreciated for your response. I didn't know "No heavy uses (an absolute maximum of 1 request per second)." that's where I stuck, I think

Comment: @bibakcamki you're welcome. I've added a way to cache the responses. Be careful you aren't caching the requests to `nasa.gov`. And be aware of the security issues of pickle and requests-cache.